# async grpc server handling multiple types of request

Tags: grpc

Is there a better example on how to implement multiple async requests.

```
 // The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc ListSayHello1 (HelloRequest1) returns (stream HelloReply1) {}
  rpc ListSayHello2 (HelloRequest2) returns (stream HelloReply2) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest1 {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloRequest2 {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply1 {
  string message = 1;
}

message HelloReply2 {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I am using below async pattern to handle `SayHello1`, but now I want to add support for `SayHello2`. What should be the approach?

```
 new CallData(&service_, cq_.get(), *this);
    void* tag;  // uniquely identifies a request.
    bool ok;
    while (true) {
        // Block waiting to read the next event from the completion queue. The
        // event is uniquely identified by its tag, which in this case is the
        // memory address of a CallData instance.
        // The return value of Next should always be checked. This return value
        // tells us whether there is any kind of event or cq_ is shutting down.
        GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
        GPR_ASSERT(ok);
        static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
    }
```

In `CallData`, I doing this

```
void CallData::Proceed()
{
    if (status_ == CREATE) {

        status_ = PROCESS;
        service_->RequestListSayHello1(&ctx_, &request_, &writer_, cq_, cq_,
            this);
    }
... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. 
For every protobuf function, I had to create separate completion queue.

Comment: Hey I'm trying to figure this out myself. Could you post your code for viewing please?

Answer (score 7):

It is not necessary to create extra completion queues. We just need to know how to handle what the completion queue returns. We can solve this by making a common base class, that is able to do the necessary functions:

```
class CallDataBase
{
protected:
    virtual void WaitForRequest() = 0;
    virtual void HandleRequest() = 0;
public:
    virtual void Proceed() = 0;
    CallDataBase() {}
};
```

Each specialization of CallDataBase know how to Proceed, WaitForRequest and HandleRequest. Some of this is common for all requests, so it is convenient to use a templatized class:

```
template < class RequestType, class ReplyType>
class CallDataT : CallDataBase
{
protected:
    enum CallStatus { CREATE, PROCESS, FINISH };
    CallStatus status_;

    Greeter::AsyncService* service_;
    ServerCompletionQueue* completionQueue_;
    RequestType request_;
    ReplyType reply_;
    ServerAsyncResponseWriter<ReplyType> responder_;
    ServerContext serverContext_;

    // When we handle a request of this type, we need to tell
    // the completion queue to wait for new requests of the same type.
    virtual void AddNextToCompletionQueue() = 0;
public:
    CallDataT(Greeter::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* completionQueue) :
        status_(CREATE),
        service_(service),
        completionQueue_(completionQueue),
        responder_(&serverContext_)
    {
    }
public:
    virtual void Proceed() override
    {
        if (status_ == CREATE)
        {
            status_ = PROCESS;
            WaitForRequest();
        }
        else if (status_ == PROCESS)
        {
            AddNextToCompletionQueue();
            HandleRequest();
            status_ = FINISH;
            responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
        }
        else
        {
            // We're done! Self-destruct!
            if (status_ != FINISH)
            {
                // Log some error message
            }
            delete this;
        }
    }
};
```

And finally, the actual implementation of the message types:

```
class CallDataHello : CallDataT<HelloRequest, HelloReply>
{
public:
    CallDataHello(Greeter::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* completionQueue) : CallDataT(service, completionQueue)
    {
        Proceed();
    }
protected:
    virtual void AddNextToCompletionQueue() override
    {
        new CallDataHello(service_, completionQueue_);
    }
    virtual void WaitForRequest() override
    {
        service_->RequestSayHello(&serverContext_, &request_, &responder_, completionQueue_, completionQueue_, this);
    }
    virtual void HandleRequest() override
    {
        reply_.set_message(std::string("Hello ") + request_.name());
    }
};

class CallDataHelloAgain : CallDataT<HelloAgainRequest, HelloAgainReply>
{
public:
    CallDataHelloAgain(Greeter::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* completionQueue) : CallDataT(service, completionQueue)
    {
        Proceed();
    }
protected:
    virtual void AddNextToCompletionQueue() override
    {
        new CallDataHelloAgain(service_, completionQueue_);
    }
    virtual void WaitForRequest() override
    {
        service_->RequestSayHelloAgain(&serverContext_, &request_, &responder_, completionQueue_, completionQueue_, this);
    }
    virtual void HandleRequest() override
    {
        reply_.set_message(std::string("Hello again ") + request_.name());
    }
};
```

Finally, in the GRPC server implementation, we can then handle the different requests in a unified way:

```
void HandleRpcs() 
{
    new CallDataHello(&service_, completionQueue.get());
    new CallDataHelloAgain(engine_, &service_, completionQueue.get());
    void* tag;
    bool ok;
    while (true) {
        bool ret = completionQueue->Next(&tag, &ok);
        if (ok == false || ret == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        static_cast<CallDataBase*>(tag)->Proceed();
    }
}
```

This works because all the CallData we add to completionQueue, is of baseclass CallDataBase, so we can safely call Proceed() on them. This approach makes it relatively easy to add new requests. All the requests are handled by the same completion queue. However, all the requests will be handled serially, so if you are after more parallel processing, I think you have to make more than one completion queue.

Comment: I can not figure out, when Proceed is called with FINISH status

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you for taking the time to write up such a good example.